# How to connect esp32 and esp8266 with redis database as client

Tags: redis, raspberry-pi3, esp8266, node-redis, esp32

i am trying to run redis server database on RPi3 M-B and want to connect esp12N (esp8266 based) and esp32 with the database as client.

Also suggest me if any other database other than redis which is supported in both raspberry pi as well as esp32/ esp8266.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a redis library for the ESP8266 using the Arduino SDK available at https://github.com/remicaumette/esp8266-redis

You can find libraries like this very easily by searching Google for things like "redis library esp8266". You can also find it by searching the Library Manager in the Arduino SDK, or [searching Platformio's libraries](https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=redis).

Comment: Thanks a lot john, I managed it to work on esp8266 but want to run on esp32-Wroom, there i am stucked. Kindly help.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the library of esp8266 to work on esp32-wrooom?

Comment: Yes, it will require a small amount of rewriting - the ESP32 SDK uses slightly different header file names (for instance, "WiFi.h" instead of "ESP8266Wifi.h") but most of the methods on the classes it uses should be about the same. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks John. I will just give a try to this.